# Cross site scripting problems with testacular e2e tests and angular

Tags: tomcat, angularjs, karma-runner

I am building a webapp with a using java at the server and angular for the front end. I am trying to set up e2e tests using testacular. The tests fail beacause of what I assume is cross site scripting problems. Since I build my back end using java, I have a tomcat server running hosting my web app. If I navigate to `http://localhost:8087/angular` in my browser, the page loads. (The port 8087 is for my tomcat 7 installation since I have both tomcat 6 and 7 on my computer).

When I run `testacular start 'path/to/config/file` I get this error:

```
http://localhost:9876/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js?1360780804000:25281: 
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

This is my config file:

```
basePath = '../../';

files = [ 
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/js/tests/e2e/scenarios.js'
];

autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['firefox'];

singleRun = true;

proxies = { 
  '/': 'http://localhost:8087/angular'
};

junitReporter = { 
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

And this is my test file:

```
describe("E2E Test", function() {

    it("should load the document and be able to read from it", function() {
        browser().navigateTo("/");
        expect(element("body", "The body element").count()).toBe(1); 
    }); 

});
```

Is there any way around this?
Using:
node v0.8.20
testacular 0.5.10

Comment: are you running node/web server when you run karma in the command line?

Comment: I don't understand. What is karma? I am using tomcat as a web server. It has been a while since I asked this and one solution for me was to write the e2e tests in java using selenium.

Comment: Karma is the new name of testacular. It's possible that updating to the latest might change either the problem or the error message.

Comment: Hi Ludwig, there was a problem running Karma with 1.0.6 version of Angular, you need to use 1.4.4 version. Not sure if it help solve the problem. I would strongly recommend look at Karma/Testacular than Selimium.

Comment: has the issue been resolved?

Comment: Since I asked this question I have updated to karma (currently 0.8). I do not use tomcat/java at the moment. But I recently did some quick testing with it and I did not manage to make it work. The error was not the same however. I will not investigate this further at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd recommend that you upgrade [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html)

The configuration you've shared should work just as well as the one in [this here example](http://steve-mosley.com/blog/2013/3/29/karma-testacular-angularjs-e2e-test-configuration). The fact that it doesn't is either caused by the fact that you're using an old version of testacular, OR by an issue in your application itself.

I've had some luck with older versions of testacular/angular when I served everything from port 80 using Nginx, but I would upgrade first if I were you.